# Styling a TableView scroll-bar in CSS (JavaFX)

Tags: css, javafx, scroll, styles, tableview

How can I style the "THIS" point in my TableView?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styleClass you are looking for is `.corner`

In your applications .css file you can apply the style you like e.g.

```
.corner {-fx-background-color: green;}
```

When you need to know a styleClass of a component, you can use the CSS Analyzer in Scenebuilder (View -> Show CSS Analyzer), or [Scenicview](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/%22ScenicView%22) which is even more convenient

Answer (score 0):

This area is a StackPane which belongs to your ScrollPane.

(I assume that your ScrollPane has the id "Sp")

Then style it like:

```
#Sp>StackPane {
    -fx-background-color: #ff0000;
}
```